# How to replace multiline successive

Tags: python

I want to transform a three lines successive contains '}' by three others lines like this:

```
{
{
{
aa
bbb
ccc
}
}
}
```

to

```
{
{
{
aa
bbb
ccc
}
}
},
```

For the single line replace, I did this:

```
with open("in.txt", "rt") as fin:
    with open("out.txt", "wt") as fout:
        for line in fin:
            fout.write(line.replace('}\n', '},\n'))
```

and it works fine.

When I tried to replace three line successive, I did this

```
fout.write(line.replace('}\n}\n}', '}\n}\n},'))
```

but it does not work.

How to correctly replace several successive lines using python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it, to transform it in a single line before replacing:

```
with open("in.txt", "rt") as fin:
   with open("out.txt", "wt") as fout:
      text = ''.join(fin).replace('}\n}\n}', '}\n}\n},')
      fout.write(text)
```

Alternatively, if you want to different lines you can trick it like this but it's not very clean :

```
with open("in.txt", "rt") as fin:
   with open("out.txt", "wt") as fout:
      text = '_'.join(fin).replace('}\n_}\n_}', '}\n_}\n_},') # Join in one line
      for line in text.split('_')) : # Re split in different lines
          fout.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Count the opening braces, and only add a comma when each opening brace has been closed.

```
depth = 0
with open("in.txt", "rt") as fin:
    with open("out.txt", "wt") as fout:
        for line in fin:
            line = line.rstrip()

            if line == "{":
                depth += 1
            elif line == "}":
                depth -= 1

            if depth == 0 and line == "}":
                fout.write(line + ",\n")
            else:
                fout.write(line + "\n")
```